# What is the structure of this sentence with commas?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

In the sentence below

> The processor puts the data it wants to write on a bank of electrical traces, the data bus, by raising the voltage on some to represent ones and leaving voltages unchanged on others to represent zeros.

What is the relationship between 'a bank of electrical traces' and 'the data bus'?
Does the sentence mean the processor put **both** on 'a bank of electrical traces' **and '**the data bus'?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "the data bus" here is a *name* for "a bank of electrical traces". I am influenced by knowing that this is the factually correct answer. The sentence could possibly be interpreted otherwise, but "the data bus" is a parenthetical, so it should give more information about the preceding grammatical object, as in fact it does here.

If the intent was that the bus and the "bank of traces" were two different things, a conjunction such as "and" should have been used between them.

Comment: the technical term is [appositive](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/appositive.htm)